# Call swift function from bash script

Tags: swift, bash, macos, events, communication

I wrote an application for macOS in Swift 3.
I would like to be able to call one the functions of the already running app from a bash script. 
Do you know a way to do it?

Maybe I have to use osascript inside my bash script and send a kind of event to my application that I will handle just calling the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to create command line app. Install it on your Mac update PATH and you can call it from bash. Alternative would be to set the full path to the app in your bash script when you call it.

I'm not sure how/if you can use your existing macOS app (if it's not a command line one) to call the function of it via bash.

Comment: I have to use an existing app, but the real problem is that the app is already running and I have to call the function multiple times as the time passes

Comment: @Nisba I think if the app doesn't expose a command line api you won't be able to call it but I'm not 100% sure.